# Cannot Find Data Type in SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) lists "TIME" as an available Data Type. This is good, since I need time variables and the ability to perform functions on them (in the form of 00:00:00). Datetime is not an option because my scheduling database cares about Monday - Sunday, not 11/13/14, etc... When i go to create a column with data type time, it doesn't exist. I also tried doing it via query:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DataSchedule
ALTER COLUMN StartClock TIME
```

And get the message:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
>   Column, parameter, or variable #6: Cannot find data type TIME.

How can I resolve this issue? Is this a problem with 2014 express as opposed to the standard edition?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you **SURE** that you're running against the 2014 instance?? What does `SELECT @@Version` tell you?

Comment: You are correct, I mistakenly connected to a database that was once upon a time, created with 2005 and when I installed 2014, it used that old instance (which was empty...). this happened despite me opening 2014 Management Studio. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Per [SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) `TIME` datatype is available from SQL Server version 2008 and above. I am pretty much sure that, you connected to a SQL Server 2005 instance and tried using the TIME datatype.

Also, it doesn't matter which SSMS version you are using to connect to since that's just the client. Make sure that, you are actually connected to a server version 2008 and above.